# Jenkins groovy dynamically create variables - what is wrong

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

This is the Jenkins groovy script where .. below is working ..at the stage "validating - line0", the content is correctly returned.

```
        stage('Read and assign value Groups') {
            steps{
                script {
                def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
                image_properties.line0 = build_properties.line0
                }
            }
        }

        stage('validating  - line0') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("Content: ${image_properties.line0}")

                     }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

However, how do we make them dynamic? The below one is not working. What is not working is, in the stage "validating - line0", the content is printing "null". Please advise what is wrong. We wanted to dynamically create the variables and assign the value to other stages.

```
        stage('Read and assign value Groups') {
            steps{
                script {
                TotalCountline = sh ( script: 'cat file.txt|wc -l', returnStdout: true).trim().toInteger()
                def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
                for(i=0;i<TotalCountModelGroup;i++) {
                    def var1="image_properties.line$i"
                    def var2="build_properties.line$i"
                   println (var1 + "="+ var2)
                    var1 = var2
                   
                }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('validating  - line0') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         println("line Content: ${image_properties.line0}")

                     }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

and `file.txt` contains

```
line0=[acme01, acme02, acme03, acme04]
line1=[acme11, acme12, acme13, acme14]
line2=[acme21, acme22, acme23, acme24]
line3=[acme31, acme32, acme33, acme34]
```

And this is declared at globally, located before "pipeline{}"

```
def (image_properties, branch) = [ [image_tags:[]], null ]
```

Comment: please edit your question and add details: `1.` file.txt file content example `2.` how image_properties declared

Comment: @daggett: extra information added..pls let usknow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[readProperties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) returns a java Map (key-value pairs)
and you can iterate it with following code:

```
def (image_properties, branch) = [ [image_tags:[]], null ]
def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
build_properties.each{ k,v ->
    image_properties[k]=v
}
```

or it could be even simpler because image_properties also a Map:

```
def (image_properties, branch) = [ [image_tags:[]], null ]
def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
image_properties.putAll(build_properties)
```

javadoc on [Map.putAll(Map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-)

Comment: If we move to the function, it fails with this below, please advise. ``` 20:43:36 hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.putAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.HashMap) values: [line2:acme21, acme22, acme23, acme24]] 20:43:36 Possible solutions: putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), findAll(), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure) 20:43:36 at ```

@daggett - any suggestion please.

Comment: for some reason you are trying to apply `putAll(...)` to a String. The variable you specifying before putAll is a string but it should be a map.