# groovy moved piece of script to function getting failed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Previously, we have this working one

```
        stage('Split and store Groups') {
            steps{
                script {
                def results = modelPartition(Directories, 4)
                assert results instanceof List
                for(i=0;i<results.size();i++)
                {
                sh """
                echo "modelgroup$i=${results[i]}" >> file.txt
                sed -i 's/[][]//g' file.txt
                """
                }
                sh """
                cat file.txt
                """
                def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
                image_properties.putAll(build_properties)
                }
            }
        }
```

and file.txt will contain

```
group0=acme01,acme02,acme03,acme04
group1=acme11,acme12,acme13,acme14
group2=acme21,acme22,acme23,acme24
group3=acme31,acme32,acme33,acme34
```

eventually all the values assigned to `image_properties` is available to further stages, like this i.e this is working as per other thread - [Jenkins groovy dynamically create variables - what is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77904708/jenkins-groovy-dynamically-create-variables-what-is-wrong/77913925#77913925)

```
        stage('Validate set - 0') {
            steps{
                script {
                     container("${opts.container}") {
                         splitAndValidate(image_properties.group0);
                     }   
                }
            }
        }
```

However, if we move the "split and store groups" script to function, likethis

```
def abilityForRestart(vDirectories) {
    def results = modelPartition(vDirectories, 4)
    assert results instanceof List
    for(i=0;i<results.size();i++)
    {
    sh """
    echo "" > file.txt
    echo "modelgroup$i=${results[i]}" >> file.txt
    sed -i 's/[][]//g' file.txt
    """
    }
    def build_properties = readProperties file: "file.txt"
    return image_properties.putAll(build_properties)
}
```

And call using this

```
stage('Split and store Model Groups') {
            steps{
                script {
                abilityForRestart(Directories)
                }
            }
        }
```

above fails with

```
20:43:36  hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.putAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.HashMap) values: [[modelgroup3:nowllm_kbgen, llm_generic, conversational_catalog]]
20:43:36  Possible solutions: putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), findAll(), getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
20:43:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:154)
```

Any resolution is pleased.

Comment: I would guess that `image_properties` has to be declared as a global variable. Maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/6315609/14583599